# Good Cocos2d iphone tutorials?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've been trying to learn Cocos2d iPhone, and I've been looking for tutorials.  Does anyone know of any good tutorials that are modern and towards beginning? I've been doing Objective-C for about 6 months, so not that beginning.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great resource for tutorials.

http://www.raywenderlich.com

Answer (score 0):

their own page have [4 Video Tutorials](http://cocos2d.org/doc.html), is this what you wanted or you want other kind of tutorials?

Comment: I did mention that I wanted the iphone version...